# how to store sql lite database in android studio to device memory?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am new to android . I would like to store and retrieve records in android studio . I am using embedded sql database in android studio . Data are inserted perfectly when my device is connected to studio. whenever, i run after disconnecting my device insertion is not performing . what is the problem ? please help me, what should i need to do?

Comment: Where are you saving this 'database'?

Comment: it is stored in emulator memory

Comment: Let me guess, are you pusing this database in your emulator's 'data/data/package/databases' folder manually?

Comment: no , i am not pushing . i want my database in device memory

Comment: Check the code, is the data even present while you are trying to insert it into database? Post your code where you are creating this database and code where you are inserting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  private void exportDB(){
  File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
   FileChannel source=null;
   FileChannel destination=null;
   String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "com.example.yourpackname" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
   String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
   File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
   File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
   try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) . I have tried your code , this also not inserting when device is not connected with android studio :(

Comment: In android studio this database back up store in emulator memory...if you run  that code in device its store in device memory..

Comment: then how to change this to device memory ?

Comment: I am doing google map based application . i would like to store my history.i have tried array of data with Sharedpreferrences , but i din't get consistent answer. data are shuffling . so, i move on to database. can you help me how do i proceed further ?

Comment: when i run in device its not storing in device memory?

Comment: Give both path  correctly based on your database and packagename ..  String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "com.example.yourpackname" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
   String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;